# ¿como solucionar el error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object?

Tags: php

No entiendo porque me lo da como error si esta idéntico a como lo tengo en otro sitio lo unico nuevo es lo de la app para las peticiones

```
require_once('DBConnection.php');
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "placidojrc");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "proyecto_fitness");
$app->get('/usuarios', function () {

$response = array();
$dbc = new DBConnection();
$sql="SELECT 'nombre' FROM usuarios";
$rs=$dbc->getQuery($sql);
$profile=$rs->fetch();
echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

Acontinuacion pongo la clase DBConnection

```
<?php

class DBConnection{

    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $db = DB_NAME;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbh;
    private $error=null;


    public function __construct(){
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        $dsn="mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";";

        try{
            $this->dbh=new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            $this->error=$ex->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $dbh=null;
    }

    public function getError(){
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function runQuery($query){
        try{
            return $this->dbh->exec($query);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            $this->error=$ex->getMessage();
            return "Error";
        }
    }

    public function getQuery($query){
        try{
            $sentencia = $this->dbh->query($query);
            $sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $sentencia;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            $this->error=$ex->getMessage();
            return "Error";
        }
    }


}?>
```

La clase DBConnection se que es la que no me da error ya que es una que utilizo en todos mis proyectos para conectarme a la base de datos.

Se que ya se han formulado preguntas similares pero no me han llegado a resolver nada y aparte me da error al usar cualquier método ya sea rowCount u otros

Comment: Prueba a quitar las comillas simples de tu consulta: *SELECT nombre FROM usuarios*

Comment: Acabo de hacer el cambio pero sigue dándome el mismo error

Comment: por lo que se ve, el problema esta en tu consulta `SELECT 'nombre' FROM usuarios` por que al parecer tu consulta no esta dando resultado por ende no puedes ejecutar `fetch()`

Comment: Prueba reemplazando la función por esta y cuéntame que te retorna 


public function getQuery($query){
        try{
            $sentencia = $this->dbh->query($query);
            $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $obj = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $obj;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            $this->error=$ex->getMessage();
            return "Error";
        }
    }

Comment: Call Stack: 0.0006 234240 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/v1/index.php:0 0.0038 375760 2. Slim\Slim->run() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/v1/index.php:119 0.0041 381560 3. Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Slim.php:1302 0.0041 381696 4. Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php:67 0.0054 402640 5. Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()

Comment: /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php:92 0.0055 403336 6. Slim\Slim->call() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php:85 0.0076 438776 7. Slim\Route->dispatch() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Slim.php:1357 0.0076 439024 8. call_user_func_array:{/home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Route.php:468}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Route.php:468 0.0076 439120 9. {closure:/home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/v1/index.php:42-62}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/restapi/libs/Slim/Route.php:468

Comment: por lo visto me da ahora eso junto a lo del non-object